# Calling a static method from other class Android Java

Tags: java, android, methods, static

How to call a method from `MainActivity`? The called method is static in another class. This code works perfectly fine on PC but fails on Android.

Here is the MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

Metode.getDatum();
}
```

The other public class `Metode`, has a static method `getDatum()`.

```
public static String getDatum() {

    Calendar koledar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int[] datum = new int[3];

    datum[0] = koledar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    datum[1] = koledar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    datum[2] = koledar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    String datumString = Arrays.toString(datum);

    return datumString;
}
```

I get "Identifier expected" after this token error.

This app has only one activity, the `Metode` class is

```
public class Metode
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem, where you try call getDatum() method? can you provide some code for this?

Comment: @Stanislav He is calling the method all the way on the bottom of the main activity, outside any method (which of course is iinvalid syntax).

Comment: @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
  Metode.getDatum();
 }

This doesn't work either. (Calling from other method). <classname> cannot be resolved. Don't hate me I make a good pie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code isn't supposed to work. You have to call `Metode.getDatum();` **from other method.**

Moreover, this method returns a `String` which is totally ignored. Probably you want use this somwhere?

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'll repeat this in my head a couple of times, create a method and come back if it works. Thank you for now.

Comment: I've got a feeling, that you don't quite understand what are you doing. Am I right?

Comment: This returned String is later used to write aquired date to a .txt file. And code works outside Android enviroment. I put the call inside a void method, and now I get "Metode cannot be resolved" and "Identifier expected after.." error again. I think I know I want to call a static method which is declared in other class.

Comment: No, calling the method in such a place is incorrect syntax, this has nothing to do with Android. It would be just as wrong in normal Java.

Comment: Oh, in Java it is called from the main method..Thanks, guys. But, still. Any suggestions? I do my work around books, but in the meantime, I like to code something.

Comment: Learning programming by Android is rather hardcore. I'd suggest to try some [simpler examples](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/codingSamples.htm) first.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I thought there is just some GUI to be created for the app to work on Android, but it's far beyond this. Thank you for examples. Kindest regards, Boris.

Comment: But, ehm.. Ifffff you happen to think of a solution, I'll buy you a beer.

Comment: @BorisCerar You can, for instance, call `Metode.getDatum();` inside `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method. Then your code should compile.

Comment: Thank you, Kao! I'll try experimenting this in the evening. Owe you a beer!

Comment: @Kao Hey, I'll send you a Laško and a Union, after we solve this (I prefer Union). Anyway, putting the call inside the onCreateOptionsMenu does not do the trick, I get the error Metode (classname) cannot be resolved. In any case, this metod does not need to be in another class to do its function, I just want to learn  how to f*ing do this and why it doesn't work this way. I was sure as hell happy to learn how to call a method from another class on PC, and I'll be damned if I have to unlearn this. :) Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like there was a problem in package declaration.

```
****package com.example.sluzba;****



import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Metode {

public static String getDatum() {

Calendar koledar = Calendar.getInstance();

int[] datum = new int[3];

datum[0] = koledar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
datum[1] = koledar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
datum[2] = koledar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

String datumString = Arrays.toString(datum);

return datumString;
```

}

Now it runs, if I call it from other method.

So I guess, package declaration (correct me if naming isn't correct) is important. Just saying, if a n00b like me gets into the same lamery.
 Thank you, everyone!!! Kao and others. Cheers!